# Present perfect vs present perfect continuous difference

Tags: grammar, meaning, difference, present-perfect

1.How long have you stayed in hotel?
2.How long have you been staying in hotel?

Are these both grammatically correct and have the same meaning?

Or first mean I was in this hotel but now I am in other place(like finished action)and second like I am still in this hotel or the first also mean I am still in hotel

Answer (score 1):

First, you need an article - probably *the* - before "hotel".

Second - both are possible, but I find the continuous "How long have you been staying" more natural - probably because the question is about length of time, so it makes more sense to use the form which focuses on the extended activity (or state).

As to your second question: using the perfect means that there is relevance to the present; so much the most likely interpretation (of either form) is that you are still in the hotel. I can imagine the first ("How long have you stayed in the hotel") in a case when your stay in the hotel is finished, but it is seen as part of something that is still going on - perhaps you are on a trip, and have stayed in other places since the hotel - but I'm having difficulty coming up with a plausible context for it; so I think it is possible, but not likely.